# Ubuntu on Mac G5 PowerPC

Tags: mac, powerpc

I have downloaded the ISO at https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ubuntu-11-10-powerpc-installation/ for a Power PC. Than i burned it on a CD. Does anyone know how to boot the Mac from there?

I tried Cmd, Opt and Delete
Also the BOOT-CD-ROM Command from Open Firmware...https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/ch05s01.html

Can anyone help me?

Comment: PPC support ended in 2019-April, with now only `ppc64el` being a supported architecture.  Ubuntu 11.10 is years past it's EOL and thus unsupported (off-topic) on this site. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is bring up the menu to select a boot device, you can do this:

1. Turn the machine on / Reboot
2. Immediately hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key until the boot selection screen appears

This usually takes around 10 seconds

Comment: This was the first i tried....but it only shows my hard drive